# Required attribute dependent on another attribute's value (ASP.NET Core Web Api)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, data-annotations

I have a model class and I want to make on the parameter "required" only if the value of another parameter is something.

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumConverter))]
[Required]
public AddressTagEnum AddressTagId { get; set; }

[RequiredIf("AddressTagId", 3)]
[MaxLength(20)]
public string AddressTagOther { get; set; }
```

How can I achieve this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are several ways to solve your problem:

1. there is no standard way to do this
2. there are librariers e.g. [Expressive Annotations](https://github.com/jwaliszko/ExpressiveAnnotations) that should help
3. there is a built-in attribute `Remote` that lets you perform a server validation like: `[Remote(action: "VerifyEmail", controller: "Users")]` see [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

i prefer (i know that this is opinion based) a implementation with `IValidatableObject`. Citing the docs:

```
public class ValidatableMovie : IValidatableObject
{
    private const int _classicYear = 1960;

    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [Display(Name = "Release Date")]
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(1000)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Range(0, 999.99)]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public Genre Genre { get; set; }

    public bool Preorder { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (Genre == Genre.Classic && ReleaseDate.Year > _classicYear)
        {
            yield return new ValidationResult(
                $"Classic movies must have a release year no later than {_classicYear}.",
                new[] { nameof(ReleaseDate) });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/jwaliszko/ExpressiveAnnotations worked. Thanks!